# Why do I get a blank screen on booting in Windows 8 Developer Preview (x64)?

Tags: boot, drivers, graphics-card, windows-8-preview

**Basic system info:**

```
OS: Windows 8 Developer Preview (x64)
CPU: Intel Core2 Duo
Graphics: Intel integrated/ATI Mobility Radeon HD4330
```

**The problem:**

1. After installation everything works fine and it boots to the desktop
2. At some point later (seemingly randomly) the screen goes blank (but still on), then turns off, and then on again (but is still blank)
3. After this when the computer is restarted a blank screen appears instead of the boot options after the initial boot logo has shown.

So on initial thoughts it appears it may be a graphics issue. I have tried system restore/repair to no avail.

In a nutshell: why do I get a blank screen, and how can I get my display back?

**Further info**:

It turns out that after the problem has occurred, putting the computer to sleep and waking it up brings back the display. This technique (putting it to sleep then waking up) also seems to work when the screen is blank after booting, as long as enough time is left that the computer gets past the boot options and to the logon screen before you put it to sleep.

After some more testing (*cough* reformatting and re-installing) I can confirm that a) after re-installing from the CD all is fine for a while, but b) the problem re-appears after a short peroid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe I have solved my own problem, so I shall leave this information here should anyone else encounter something similar:

The first step was re-installing Windows 8 without allowing a network connection. After several reboots and hibernations everything worked fine, until I enabled a network connection.
Shortly after enabling network connections (2) happens.

Then I re-installed Windows 8 again making sure Windows Updates were set turned off and network connections disabled. Under these conditions I encountered no problems after re-enabling network connections, so the issue lies with one or more updates applied.

After some more tinkering I have identified the offending update as the "AMD, Inc. driver update for ATI Mobility Radeon HD 4300 Series (Engineering Sample)" driver.

**TL;DR: If you get blank screen issues and have a Radeon HD 4300 series card then it is probably an issue with the driver update from AMD. You may have to hide the update for the card in Windows Update to prevent Windows from automatically downloading it again in future.**

NB: A further update for the Radeon Mobility HD4300 driver was released on the 21st. This driver puts the graphics card into a disabled state (the device cannot start).

Comment: pre-release software ayy

Comment: Indeed, I have contacted AMD about the issue so hopefully a further driver update will be forthcoming. Also thanks to whoever moved the post from SO to SU: my bad for putting it in the wrong place originally, I sometimes forget there are other areas of StackExchange.

Comment: Thanks for beta testing the AMD driver update for us! ;->

Answer (score 2):

After a B(lack)SOD re-start your computer whilst rapidly pressing "shift and F8", click on recovery options, then advaced options, then you will see a re-start in safe mode. Choose safe mode then uninstall your graphics driver reboot.